# Netsuite User Events Governance nlapiYieldScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We have a simple user event script that loads alot of line items before handling. Ive seen this done in scheduled scripts, but curious to know if this is possible to be used in User events.

```
if (nlapiGetContext().getRemainingUsage() < 100)
                  {
                    nlapiYieldScript();
                  }
```

Would this snippet of code allow for bypassing the governance on a user event script and allow it to keep processing?

Answer (score 1):

nlapiYieldScript is only for a scheduled script and it will not work in any other script.

Answer (score 1):

Your user event script really shouldn't need that much governance to do whatever it is trying to do.  nlapiYieldScript is only for Scheduled Scripts.

Rather than "loading" your items, it might be easier to iterate through the line items, and get the item ids.  Then do a search for those ids.  That way you don't load anything.

It's a simple search and getValue call.

Comment: There's no need to iterate through the lines. All you need to do is call a transaction search (filter with transaction internalid) joining the item fields or the other way around item search joining transaction field (filter with transaction internalid)